# Powershell join array values

Tags: arrays, powershell, cross-product

I'm looking to cross combine values of arrays to create new array. example,

```
$a = @('Blue','red','green') 
$b = @('car', 'bike')
```

to something like

`('blue car','red car','green car')` and `('blue bike','red bike','green bike')`

PS: this is not simple concatenate function I'm looking.

Thanks,
Nilay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
$a = @('Blue', 'red', 'green') 
$b = @('car', 'bike') 

$outArrays = @(), @() # Initialize a 2-element array.
$i = 0
foreach ($elB in $b) {
  $outArrays[$i++] = foreach ($elA in $a) { "$elA $elB" }
}
```

- `$outArrays[0]` now contains `'blue car', 'red car', 'green car'`
- `$outArrays[1]` now contains `'blue bike', 'red bike', 'green bike'`

The above takes advantage of PowerShell's ability to use loop statements such as [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) as *expressions*, with PowerShell implicitly collecting all outputs from the loop in an *array* (`[object[]]`; assuming *two or more* outputs).

---

**General information about array concatentation**:

To create a *flat* array, by concatenation, simply use `+`:

```sh
# Creates a flat array with 5 elements:
#   @('Blue', 'red', 'green', 'car', 'bike')
$a + $b
```

To create a two-element *nested* array, use the unary form of `,`, the [array constructor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-):

```sh
# -> Nested 2-element array:
# * Element 0 contains @('Blue', 'red', 'green')
# * Element 1 contains: @('car', 'bike')
, $a + , $b
```

As an aside: note that you don't strictly need [`@(...)`, the array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) to create array literals; e.g.,
`$a = 'Blue', 'red', 'green'` will do.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a matrix with this approach

```
# your input
$a = @('Blue','red','green') 
$b = @('car', 'bike')
# create an empty result array
$result = @()
# iterate the input arrays and add the items to the result
$b | ForEach-Object { $x=$_; $a | ForEach-Object { $result +=  "$_ $x" } }
```

The `+=` operator is not very efficient. It will create a new instance of the result for each iteration. This might work for small input arrays.